# The index of the centraliser of an element of a group equals the order of its conjugation class.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $x \in G$. The conjugation class of $x$ is:

$$ Cl(x) = \{ y \in G \mid \exists g \in G, y=gxg^{-1} \} $$

And the centraliser of $x$ in $G$ is:

$$ C_G (x) = \{ g \in G \mid gx=xg \} $$

Show that $|Cl(x)| = |G:C_G (x)|$.

I have been working in this proposition for many hours. It appears in the notes of an introduction course in group theory. I have tried to build an isomorfism from $Cl(x)$ to $G/C_G (x)$ but I think $C_G (x)$ it's not a normal group, so I don't know how to keep working.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Consider the map $g C_G(x) \mapsto gxg^{-1}$. Check that it's well-defined, injective, and surjective.

Comment: The normality of a subgroup $H$ is a requirement for the coset space $G/H$ to be a group, but the coset space $G/H$ itself exists regardless of if $H$ is normal or not. The proposition here is a special case of the orbit-stabilizer theorem: if $G$ acts on a set $\Omega$, then the size of an orbit ${\rm Orb}(\omega)$ equals the index of the stabilizer (i.e. size of its coset space), $|G/{\rm Stab}(\omega)|$. Here $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, orbits are conjugacy classes, and stabilizers are centralizers of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, we consider the map $\phi : G / C_G (x) \to Cl(x)$ defined by $\phi (g C_G(x)) = gxg^{-1}$.

Note, we do not require that $G / C_G(x)$ is a group. Rather, $G / C_G(x) = \{g C_G(x) : G \in G\}$ is merely the set of left cosets of $C_G(x)$ in $G$.

All we have to do is show that $\phi$ is a bijection. We have to check 3 things:

1. $\phi$ is well defined. That is, if $g_1 C_G(x) = g_2 C_G(x)$, then $\phi(g_1 C_G(x)) = \phi (g_2 C_G(x))$.
2. $\phi$ is a surjection.
3. $\phi$ is an injection.

I'll show 1, as that is usually the part people overlook. If  $g_1 C_G(x) = g_2 C_G(x)$ then $g_1 = g_2 y$ for some $y \in C_G(x)$. We have
\begin{align}
\phi(g_1 C_G(x)) &= g_1 x g_1^{-1} = (g_2 y) x (g_2 y)^{-1}
\\&= g_2 y x y^{-1} g_2^{-1} = g_2 x yy^{-1} g_2^{-1}
\\&= g_2 x g_2^{-1} = \phi (g_2 C_G(x))
\end{align}
which shows that $\phi$ is well defined.

Proving that $\phi$ is an injection essentially amounts to reversing the argument for 1.

Finally, $\phi$ is obviously a surjection (why?).

Having established 1, 2, and 3, we conclude $\phi$ is a bijection, i.e. $| G / C_G (x) | = |Cl (x)|$.

---

What is the moral of this problem? To show that two sets have the same size, exhibit a bijection. For undergraduate math, the necessary bijection will usually be the only bijection that makes sense.